# Заморозить все потоки стороннего процесса

Tags: c++builder, c++, многопоточность

Приветствую всех.

Имеется процесс "AB.EXE", он имеет 2 потока, когда ставишь "AB.EXE" на паузу "SUSPEND", то сперва оба потока процесса приостанавливаются, но затем через 1 секунду один из потоков самостоятельно возобновляется.

**Необходимо по таймеру с заданны интервалом SUSPEND'ить потоки процесса "AB.EXE"**.

Помогите, пожалуйста, если кто располагает навыками решения данной задачи!

Comment: @cuvunusij, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто. Имея id процесса (вы же знаете, откуда его взять, да?), вы можете обойти все потоки этого процесса, как в [этом примере](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Каждый из потоков можно заморозить при помощи [`SuspendThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). У вашего процесса должно быть достаточно прав для этого.

Не забудьте, что процесс в принципе может активно сопротивляться. Поскольку вы замораживаете потоки один за одним, незамороженные потоки могут следить и разморозить остальные потоки в то время, как вы пытаетесь заморозить остальные. Или отдельный процесс, сотрудничающий с тем, который вы замораживаете, может разморозить его. В общем, à la guerre comme à la guerre.

---

Как правильно отметил [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim), вы можете подключиться к процессу как отладчик. Используйте для этого функцию [`DebugActiveProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), она присоединяет вас к процессу и останавливает все его потоки. Не забудьте корректно [отсоединиться](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) от процесса, когда вам больше не нужно будет его контролировать.

Comment: А есть какой либо способ который 100% заморозит все потоки?

В этом процессе ДВА потока, ПЕРВЫЙ если замораживаешь он стоит на паузе, и есть ВТОРОЙ поток он то и саморазмораживается и является основный если его кикнуть то валится весь процесс.

Comment: на всякое действие есть противодействие. Поэтому универсального способа нет.

Но можно притвориться отладчиком и начать отладку нужного процесса:)

Comment: @cuvunusij: Универсального способа нет, всё равно это борьба стены и тарана. Пробуйте!